# Series parallel resistor. Circuit redraw

Tags: parallel, series

Can somebody help me redraw this circuit so it'll become easier to see what resistors are in series and what in parallel. 
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]
Have I redrawn the circuit correctly. Are R1 and R3 in parallel ?

Comment: You should learn how to do it yourself. If you have to ask the internet every time you need to solve a circuit, your circuits homework is going to take a _looooong_ time.

Comment: I have a test tomorrow and I needed to revise them. This is the first time I am asking. If you could answer my question I would be happy :D, because probably next time I won't need to ask :D

Comment: You'd do better to post what you think is correct and ask if you got it right.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think you are right, but I need these answers now because my test is tomorrow and I want to have good results. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you can't figure these out, you're doomed on your test.

Comment: Both of these are fairly easy. Just note which tracks are the + node and which are the ground node (of the voltage source). Put + node at top and gnd at bottom, then line the suckers up vertically between the two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try redrawing it with the 'common' which happens to be the battery (-) on the bottom and the battery (+) on the top:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGatVz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>